# Solr query field fallback

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4, solr-query-syntax

I have the following fields indexed in Solr:

- FIELD_1
- FIELD_2
- FIELD_3

I would like to search for a document where FIELD_3=X but if FIELD_3 is empty (or non existent in the document), to search in FIELD_2, and then in FIELD_1

Is this kind of query possible in Solr ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you only want to search against FIELD2 and FIELD1 if the previous fields are *empty* (and not if they have a value, but it didn't generate a hit), something like:

```
q=FIELD3:foo OR (FIELD2:foo AND NOT FIELD3:[* TO *]) OR (FIELD1:foo AND NOT FIELD2:[* TO *] AND NOT FIELD3:[* TO *])
```

should work.